# inline form in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have 2 input fields next to each other in a (bootstrap-css) col-md, but can't seem to get it right.

Here is what I have so far
https://jsfiddle.net/9hrx59bd/

It also doesn't help when I put both input fields in the same input group, by removing this:

```
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="input-group ">
```

How can I get them next to each other, and use the full width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make both input-groups a col-md-6, here is the result: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9hrx59bd/4/)

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline" id="searchform" action=""  accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
        <div class="input-group  col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <input class=" form-control " placeholder="city" id="location"  type="text" name="location">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group  col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <input class="search-query form-control newtab-search-text" placeholder="keywords or company name" id="kw"  type="text" name="job">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Edit**
I made it work on smaller screens by adding col-sm-6 and col-xs-6 aswell

Comment: that does not place them on the same line. I don't see any difference in what you linked.

Comment: @lxer I'm sorry but it does place them on the same line, are you sure you clicked the right link? Or you need to make the html space in the fidlle bigger.

Comment: thanks, making the html space larger seems to help.  Any idea how to make it work on smaller columns also?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap Inline Form

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">




    <form id="searchform" action="" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class=" form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="city" id="location" type="text" name="location">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <input class="search-query form-control newtab-search-text" placeholder="keywords or company name" id="kw" type="text" name="job">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                        <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span>
          </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>


    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please Checkout @lxer

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a `form-control` and an `input-group`.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form-inline" id="searchform" action="" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="city" id="location" type="text" name="location">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="search-query form-control newtab-search-text" placeholder="keywords or company name" id="kw" type="text" name="job">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/QPFdzLuBdJ)

***EDIT***: Another option is to use the grid columns, but remove the padding:

```
.pr-0{
    padding-right:0;
}
.pl-0{
    padding-left:0;
}

<form class="row" id="searchform" action="" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 pr-0">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="city" id="location" type="text" name="location">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 pl-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="search-query form-control newtab-search-text" placeholder="keywords or company name" id="kw" type="text" name="job">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

See the 2nd item in the [demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/QPFdzLuBdJ)

Comment: Do you know why the fields are not filling up the space of the col-md-6?

Comment: I thought you'd already accepted an answer. I edited my answer to provide an alternate option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the `input` next to each other, refer code:

Please view the results in full page view.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form action="" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</form>
```